# Read QR Code without using other app

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I want implement an activity that when starts, capture the QR code by camera, and than decode it. Can I do this without installing an other app on my tablet?
I seen zxing, but I don't understand how implements it..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.   You will have to:
 - initialise camera and start preview mode
 - wait for  preview image and process it
 - pass it to zxing library to decode.

Good starting point:  zxIng demo applications - sources are available

Comment: Sorry, but how can pass the preview to zxing library?

Answer (score 0):

Use opensource QR code projects and use them for your app.  [zxing is one](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Answer (score -1):

Try using latest zxing liberary.
You can use it by two ways,

1. Add the zxing library to your workespace and make it as liberay project.
2. Add all the file of the zxing liberary to your project.

The second option is much easier. You have to make changes in CaptureActivity according to your requirements. Its very easy.